# Visualize overlapping categories in one-hot encoding Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning, data-science

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

[image]

One instance can have a value of 1 in more than one category. I was wondering how to visualize the categories that overlap the most with each other. I thought of maybe Venn's diagrams, but I don't know ow to generate them from my position.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe could you compute the overlapping between categories pair-wise, then plot the resulting matrix with a heat map for visualization purpose, with `plt.matshow` ?

With `A` the numpy array of the one hot labels, of shape `(N, d)`, `N` the number of examples, `d` the number of categories, I would do:

```
common_occurences = A.T@A
```

This does the cross product of each category with each other, thus every value of the resulting matrix is the count of how often has a category occured with another in the examples.

Then, you can have a global visualization.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.matshow(common_occurences)
```

You might want to normalize your matrix if some categories are overall more present than other in the dataset, because their pair co-occurences will be much higher than others, eventhough they don't happen together more frequently than not.